# requestWindowFeature on SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

It's showing a `NullPointerException` on this line

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

And I guess that I have used `requestWindowFeature` in exact location.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Featured"),
            EventsFeatured.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("All"), EventsAll.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Nearby"), EventsNearBy.class,
            null);

}
```

You can find entire code here http://pastebin.com/74a8shqs

logcat:
[image]

Comment: I think you are getting problem because of `setContentView(mViewPager);` means you are not setting proper layout.

Share LogCat.

Comment: @AhmedNawaz LogCat is shared now.. :)

Comment: what is line#37 in your code? Is it not an easy thing to solve?

Comment: @Gopinath `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` this is line 37.

Comment: @Gopinath Please look the entire code here http://pastebin.com/74a8shqs

Comment: so bar is null here. ActionBar is not available in your case because you are not using a holo theme from Sherlock library. You need to set the theme to holo in your manifest file for the corresponding activity or the complete application to @style/Holo.Theme or any subset of it.

Comment: @Gopinath For the entire application I'm using this theme `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"` Do you want me to use Holo.Theme??